# Jira plugin launching, but not displaying anything in browser

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Im following the Jira plugin development, and I am unable to have jira show up in the browser when the instance is running.

everything seems to be running just fine

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 20, 2015 10:39:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-2990"]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 20, 2015 10:39:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jul 20, 2015 10:39:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Server startup in 17847 ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 7.x started on port [2990]
[INFO] jira started successfully in 46s at http://rjOS.local:2990/jira
[INFO] Type Ctrl-D to shutdown gracefully
[INFO] Type Ctrl-C to exit

jira-menu-items/ $ java -version                                                                                                                                           [22:43:57]
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

atlas-version:

```
RJ:jira-menu-items/ $ atlas-version                                                                                                                                           [22:44:03]

ATLAS Version:    5.1.6
ATLAS Home:       /usr/local/Cellar/atlassian-plugin-sdk/5.1.6/libexec
ATLAS Scripts:    /usr/local/Cellar/atlassian-plugin-sdk/5.1.6/libexec/bin
ATLAS Maven Home: /usr/local/Cellar/atlassian-plugin-sdk/5.1.6/libexec/apache-maven-3.2.1
--------
Executing: /usr/local/Cellar/atlassian-plugin-sdk/5.1.6/libexec/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn --version -gs /usr/local/Cellar/atlassian-plugin-sdk/5.1.6/libexec/apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/atlassian-plugin-sdk/5.1.6/libexec/apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: I have also tried localhost:2990/jira

Comment: did you try to delete target, kill tomcat process and re-run?

Answer (score 1):

Jira application was started as message mention in maven console but it might started unsuccessful. Please read Jira application log instead of maven console for exactly what is happening in this case. If you do not know where to find Jira application log files, please refer to this resource - https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/where-are-the-application-server-logs-16121981.html